# Problems to use embedded EJBContainer in Glassfish 4.0

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, glassfish-4, glassfish-embedded

I'm working on Junit tests do validate SessionBeans in my project. There are a local session bean with no interfaces and I want to lookup it in my test.

So, I put this dependence in pom.xml of my ejb module (same of the test):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

So, I've build my test method:

```
 @Test
public void authenticateUser() throws NamingException {

    EJBContainer container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
    AccessControlService service = (AccessControlService)container.getContext().lookup("java:global/app/module/AccessControlService");
    UserCredentials cred = new UserCredentials("admin", AccessControlUtil.getEncryptedPassword("adminadmin".toCharArray()));
    try {
        AccessControlSession session = service.authenticate(cred);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AccessControlTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

After execute the test, I received this exception stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: EJB6001:Caught exception instantiating EmbeddedContainer.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.AbstractActiveDescriptor.<init>(Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorType;Lorg/glassfish/hk2/api/DescriptorVisibility;ILjava/lang/Boolean;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.DomDescriptor.<init>(DomDescriptor.java:56)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Dom.register(Dom.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:245)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:238)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:231)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.handleElement(ConfigParser.java:190)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:100)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.DomainXml.parseDomainXml(DomainXml.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.DomainXml.run(DomainXml.java:117)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigurationPopulator.populateConfig(ConfigurationPopulator.java:58)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.bootstrap.HK2Populator.populateConfig(HK2Populator.java:158)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.populateConfig(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.bootstrap.Main.createServiceLocator(Main.java:273)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.StaticGlassFishRuntime.newGlassFish(StaticGlassFishRuntime.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:129)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:102)
    at br.com.dynavideo.AccessControlTest.authenticateUser(AccessControlTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

I also tried to set EJBContainer properties as provider, appname or module. But the same error occurs. Any ideas how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Solved it for me (with a different approach):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
       <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1-b02</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```